# Python- Selenium/BeautifulSoup PDF & Table scraper

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a code that is a robust web scraper that can be used on a variety of key words, which is formatted currently to find the first pdf it finds from the first page of a google search and if not found then it clicks into the first google search link and then grabs the closest HTML table and stores it into a pandas dataframe which will later be sent to pd._to_excel to change it into an excel file. I've asked a few questions like this before but I believe I have a decent amount of components:

```
a = ["term 1", "term 2 ", "term 3"]
b = ["school 1", "school 2 ", "school 3"]
c = ["program 1", "program 2", "program 3"]



keys = []
        
for x,y,z in [(x,y,z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]:
    keys.append(z +" "+ x +" "+ y)
    
    
path_to_driver = r"C:\wherever_you_chose_the_download_path_to_be\chromedriver.exe"

download_dir = r"C:\wherever_you_want_to_place_the_downloaded_file\name_of_pdf_holder_file"


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": download_dir,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
})
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_driver, options=chrome_options)
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

for k, key in enumerate(keys):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

        sleep_between_interactions = 5
        searchbar = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        searchbar.send_keys(key)
        searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        searchbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        pdf_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]"))
        key_index_number = str(keys.index(key) +1 )
        key_length = str(len(keys))
        print(key_index_number + " out of " + key_length)
            
        if len(pdf_element) > 0 and  key_length < key_index_number :
            print("pdf found for: "+ key)
            pdf_element[0].click()
            time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
            print("downloaded " + key_index_number + " out of "+ str(len(keys)))
                
        elif len(pdf_element) == 0 and key_index_number != key_length:
            print("pdf NOT found for "+ key)
            print(key + " pdf not downloaded, moving on...")  

            
            try:
                google_search = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={key}"
                driver.get(google_search)
                clicked_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//h3)[1]/../../a').click()
                driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                html_source_code = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
                html_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code, 'html.parser')
                url = '{}'.format(html_soup)
                r = requests.get(url)
                soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

                for table in soup.select('.table'):
                    tbl = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
                    links_column = ['{}'.format(url) + i.select_one('.*')['href'] if i.select_one('.*') is not None else '' for i in table.select('td:nth-of-type(1)')]
                    tbl['Links'] = links_column
                continue
            except:
                print("something happened, probably a JS error which will be dealt with")
                continue

                
            

            
    except IndexError as index_error:
        print("Couldn't find pdf file for "+"\"" + key + "\""+" due to Index Error moving on....")
        print(key_index_number + " out of " + str(len(keys)))
        continue
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("search bar didn't load, iterating next in loop")
        print(" pdf NOT found for "+ key)
        print(key + " pdf not downloaded, moving on...")
        continue
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        print("element either didn't load or doesn't exist")
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        continue
```

So far this works okay for finding some pdfs but it's not working for any tables it comes across.

I tried something like this in the past:

```
             url_search = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={key}"
             request = requests.get(url_search)
             soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "lxml")
             first_link = soup.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text
             links_list.append(first_link)
```

but it only returned a list of the titles of each link without actually clicking through.

Currently, I'm also thinking about how to store the pdfs by search term groupings.

Lastly, I've attempted to pass and use the html source in the past but that's also given me JavaScriptException which seems to not be an exception I can handle properly in python, I may be missing something here though.

I'm hoping also, if possible, to make the a,b,c,etc. arrays into an input() that can be used for future UI creation, not sure how doable this might be in python but it's worth a shot as long as I can get the main part of this code to work as I would like.

Not sure if this can be accomplished with XPATH or a CSS selector, or how I should go about this problem to avoid issues?

Comment: What exactly is your question / issue?

Comment: I honestly thought I typed up all that stuff as my question/issue, not sure what else to include....